# Router navigation & modal close

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm using a form component within 2 separate components in an Angular project. When the user selects 'Save' I would like my onSubmit function to close a modal if it's in one of the components or use the router link if it's in another.

I currently have my onSubmit function to finish with the router link as shown below:

```
async onSubmit() {
  this.router.navigate(['/home']);
}
```

But I would also like this to include closing a modal and not navigating when the user is in a different component.

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <app-add-form></app-drug-audit-add-form>
</div>
```

Comment: I do not see the question you are asking?

Comment: The form is used in 2 locations. In one I need it to close a modal and remain on the same page, but if used from another location I need it to use the router link and direct to another page, but not both. Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a form handler and linked this to the function.

HTML

```
<app-add-form (saveFormHandler)="onSave()"></app-add-form>
```

TS (first file)

```
@Output()
saveFormHandler = new EventEmitter();

onSubmit() {
  this.saveFormHandler.emit();
  this.saveFormHandler2.emit();
}
```

TS (second file)

```
onSave() {
  this.router.navigate(['/drug-audit']);
}
```

TS (third file)

```
onSave() {
  this.modalRef.hide();
}
```